# How to set autocommit off permanently postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres instance with a `postgres` user.

```
root@f23ada822ac8:/# su - postgres
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
$ bash
postgres@f23ada822ac8:$ psql
psql (9.6.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \echo :AUTOCOMMIT
on
```

In `/` which is postgres home directory I have .psqlrc which looks like

```
postgres@f23ada822ac8:/$ cat ~/.psqlrc
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
```

Ideally this should have set autocommit off but it doesn't switch it off. I am new to postgres. Any pointers here would help. I know this is not permanent solution. I also read that even if auto commit is on if you have transactions then it would only get committed when you call commit no matter what the auto commit setting is. Is this true?

Comment: *Why* do you want to turn Autocommit off? This is the default behaviour in all databases, even those that had it turned off by default 20+ years ago. Long transactions are bad for scalability, never mind the occasional loss of data because you forgot to commit an implicitly started transaction

Comment: `cat ~/.psqlrc` is not `cat /.psqlrc` - show the output of the last?..

Comment: Autocommit off made sense 20+ years ago because people actually typed DML commands. Applications though should hold transactions open for as little as possible. Open transactions consume resources and cause blocking, resulting in significant throughput reduction.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you have interfaced with DB's in the past. Applications like TOAD have an auto-commit feature that can be turned off, and it has saved my bacon many times. That said.

psql has a start up file psqlrc. You can add the autocommit off option to this file.  This will only work on psql however.

Comment: If you look at the question, `psqlrc` is what the OP has already tried, but it's not working. And the first paragraph here feels like a comment or a response to a different question; answers should stand alone (alongside the question they're answering) not be part of an on-going discussion.